# Optional process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I'm interested in proving that any optional process is adapted.
Here optional and adapted are used in the conventional sense but the precise definitions can be found [here](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Optional_sigma-algebra).

In the proof I'm actually using I'm confuse with two statements:

1. If $X$ is optional then $X^n:=X 1_{|X|<n}$ is also optional
2. Noting $\mathcal{O}_b$ for the set of all the optional bounded process and $\mathcal{M}:=\{$ all  bounded RCLL process $\}$ we have $\mathcal{O}_b=\sigma(\mathcal{M})$ or at least $\mathcal{O}_b \subset \sigma(\mathcal{M})$

Of course all the objects are defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P} )$

I'm stuck in proving that both this statements are valid and I will greatly appreciate any help :)

Thanks by advance,

Arthur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0. First observe that $|X|$ is optional provided that $X$ is: This follows from
   $$
   \{|X|< b\}=\{X<b\}\cap\{X\ge 0\}\cup\{X>-b\}\cap\{X<0\}\,.
   $$
1. For $b> 0\,,$
   $$
   \{X^n< b\}=\{X< b\}\cup\{|X|\ge n\}\in{\cal O}\,.
   $$
   For $b\le 0\,,$
   $$
   \{X^n< b\}=\{X< b\}\cap\{|X|<n\}\in{\cal O}\,.
   $$
   Since the Borel $\sigma$-albgebra in $\mathbb R$ is generated by the intervals $(-\infty,b)$ this shows that $X^n$ is optional.
2. You are confusing the *set* of all optional bounded processes with the $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal O}_b$ they generate.
   You denoted by ${\cal M}$ the space of all RCLL (right continuous having left limits) processes which are bounded.
   Therefore, by definition in the [link](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Optional_sigma-algebra) you provided, the optional $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal O}_b$ is equal to $\sigma({\cal M})\,.$
3. A priori, ${\cal O}_b\subset{\cal O}$ because the set of bounded optional processes is smaller than the set of optional processes. However, by point 1., every optional process $X$ is the limit of a sequence of bounded optional processes $X^n\,.$ Therefore, $X$ is measurable w.r.t. ${\cal O}_b$ which shows ${\cal O}\subset{\cal O}_b\,.$
   To summarize: ${\cal O}_b={\cal O}=\sigma({\cal M})\,.$

Comment: Hello Kurt G. and thanks for your answer. Indeed solving 1) will automatically answer 2) and as you mentioned I was a bit confuse with the definitions. Maybe a last question that still hold for me to be able to fully understand the proof is why $|X|$ is still optional (providing that $X$ is) ? Best, Arthur

Comment: I just remark that my question is a bit "trivial". It's a bit confusing at the beginning to adapt basic probability results to this specific case were the probability is pretty rich, namely $\tilde{\Omega}=\Omega \times \mathbb{R}_+$. I think the main confusion was that I didn't look at the good probability space since the beginning. Anyway, this is clear now. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: After thinking again about that I have trouble to see why $\sigma(\mathcal{M})=\mathcal{O}$, could you detail that ?

Comment: Answered. There was no need to start another question to ask exactly that .

Comment: To my point of view you are showing that the algebra generated by the bounded optional process is $\mathcal{O}$, However whatI'm looking for is to show that the algebra generated by the bounded adapted RCLL process is $\mathcal{O}$. I feel like it's not exactly the same thing. Do I miss something  ?

Comment: What we could help us is, given a RCLL adapted process $f$, a sequence of RCLL bounded adapted process converging point wise to $f$.

Comment: Does it help to consider that ${\cal O}$ is ***defined*** as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the RCLL adapted processes (see your link) ?  The play with bounded processes is an additional simple piece of cake.

Comment: This is exactly what I use, but I really need to show that restriction ourself to the bounded RCLL adapted process actually generates the same algebra. The point is that I use the monotone class theorem, thus I need to choose $\mathcal{M}$ with bounded functions. When you say this is a piece of cake do you mean it's rather simple to prove it ? In that case I would really appreciate the details as this is really a crucial point for my proof.

Comment: Here is a try: given $f$ a RCLL adapted process consider $f^{(M)}:=\min(f,M)=\frac{f+M-|f-M|}{2}$. The latter equality help us to see that $f^{(M)}$ is RCLL and $f^{(M)}_t = \min(f_t,M)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t$ measurable as  $f_t$ is. Thus we have that $f^{(M)}$ is a RCLL bounded adapted process point-wise converging to $f$. In particular using that limit of measurable functions is still measurable we can conclude. What do you think about that ?

Comment: This looks right .

Comment: Thanks for your time :)